# Hibernate hql query

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

How can i express this SQL query in HQL if we say i have the correct mappings, dtos(pojo) and configurations files...

```
    select * from sig_tc_contraloria_objetivos o  
    inner join sig_tc_contraloria_iniciativas i on o.id_objetivo = i.id_objetivo  
    inner join sig_tc_contraloria_acciones a on i.id_iniciativa = a.id_iniciativa  
    where a.id_organizacion = 8;
```

I expect as a result a List of objetivos(Parent) -> Iniciativas(Child) -> Acciones(Child)

I was trying in this way:

```
String sql = "select distinct p from SigTcContraloriaObjetivos p join p.children c join c.children b where b.idOrganizacion = 8";
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming correct mapping and configuration the following should work

```
String sql = "select distinct p from SigTcContraloriaObjetivos p join p.children c join c.children b where b.idOrganizacion = 8";
```

the difference is in the where clause. You had an `and` right after `where` and that's illegal syntax.

Comment: The problem is that query is returning me one SigTcContraloriaAccion with idOrganizacion = 9, and i still dont know why maybe is my mapping file... Please look at this image (tables of the database) http://i.stack.imgur.com/5DM1D.jpg

Comment: > Sorry, i didnt see that "and" when i wrote it here, but i my code i doesnt have that and.

Comment: ok, sorry, I thought that it would be as simple as that :-) what should the query return then. According to the image provided it is perfectly reasonable that you are getting a SigTcContraloriaAccion with idOrganizacion = 9. You should also get one with idOrganizacion = 8. no?

Comment: Yes, but how can i get only the 8 ? I dont want the 9. The query is returnning one SigTcContraloriaObjetivo, with two SigTcContraloriaIniciativa and two SigTcContraloriaAccion each of them. But I only want one in this query.

Comment: if you only want the SigTcContraloriaAccion with idOrganizacion = 8 why don't you just query for that instead of SigTcContraloriaObjetivo? Since SigTcContraloriaObjetivo with id = 1 has two SigTcContraloriaIniciativa and two SigTcContraloriaAccion it would be wrong to only load half of them when you load the object in memory. What if some behavior depends on all the kinds of SigTcContraloriaAccion an objectivo may have? It would produce an inconsistent result if you applied it on this partially initialized instance of objectivo...